# Chinese checkers adjacent squares

Tags: code-golf, array, game, board-game

### Challenge

You have a Chinese Checkers board looking like this:

```
board = [

              [''],
            ['', ''],
          ['', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
          ['', '', ''],
            ['', ''],
              ['']

];
```

Your job is that, given two inputs `a` and `b` (pointing to `board[a][b]`), you must return all the indices of the adjacent squares.

### Example

Here are a couple examples:

```
0,0 => [1,0], [1,1]
1,0 => [0,0], [1,1], [2,0], [2,1]
3,6 => [3,5], [4,5]
5,2 => [4,2], [4,3], [5,1], [5,3], [6,2], [6,3]
```

### Rules

- You can assume that the input values `a` and `b` point to a valid position in the array
- You can take in `a` and `b` as separate parameters, or an array `[a,b]`
- The order of the output doesn't matter
- You should not return the position being inputted

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: What are the neighbours of `[2,0]`? Should we include the ones diagonally adjacent (in the row below) as well?

Comment: Perhaps  you should explicitly state how all the positions are numbered. For instance, is \$[0,0]\$ the position at the very bottom? And if so, how is the position 3 rows up at the very left numbered?

Comment: The board appears to have a mistake.  I think you meant the following: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/XwEFRKurx@pwoYnoKKCJQsWg4kg8bBisM5qAPE4VROgmxn7sLifkT0SI/Of6DwA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: The 4 players on left, and right side has only 2 rows. But the players on top and bottom has 3 rows. So it must have something wrong here. Maybe you should fix your board first before accepting an answer.

Comment: @jonah  I believe it should be [like this](https://tio.run/##y/r/XwEDRKurx@pwYRHVUcAiAxWHyiHx8GGwKdFEqiOoEu6maKqYRJy7SPEp7vAiNpQR8fKf6z8A), at least...

Comment: @jonah You've fixed the problem with the staggering of the points, but you still have top and bottom points bigger than the others. It should either be a small board (delete 3rd row from top and 3rd row from bottom) or a large board like tsh